# How to create install.php including steps like a shopping cart

Tags: php, dynamic, installation

I would like to create an install.php for my tiny cms but i have a lot of questions.

-How to display install.php before the index.php?
-I would like to create steps, like in a shopping cart. The steps are:
    step1: (hi! are you ready? -submit-)
    if step1 is completed->step2:form(database-host-user-pass)->saves config.php and creates the tables
    if step2 is completed->step3:(admin username,admin pass,page title)->insert into admin
    if step3 is completed->step4:the install.php deletes itself.
-Is it possible to do it with one file?

I have most of the code of the steps in a file, the last question is, how to create steps. 
Do i have to do something with session or with some id-s? How to?

Comment: You should make more specific questions. What you want is a structure for your project based on a faint description of what you have but we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways you could do this.

1. Why not rename `install.php` to `index.php` and then rename `index.php` to something like `begin.php`
2. And then on your `begin.php` page you could do a series of divs and only display one of them at a time. When you click the "next" button, div1 would disappear, and div2 would appear. And so on and so forth. I made a jsfiddle that kind of demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/2110/ **Note that this assumes you have jquery installed.**
3. Instead of deleting `install.php` (which is now `index.php`) you would put a check at the top of `index.php` that goes something like this

   `if (installed == true) {
       //show content
   } else {
       //show installer divs
   }`

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution: http://tutsforweb.blogspot.hu/2012/02/php-installation-script.html
I hope, it will be useful to everybody with the same problem.