# I have an undefined variable, but i don't know why

Tags: php, installation, notice

This is the code i have problem with: http://tutsforweb.blogspot.hu/2012/02/php-installation-script.html

```
Notice: Undefined variable: pre_error in C:\wamp\www\torolni\install.php
on line 110 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 
10.0022297152{main}( )..\install.php:0 20.0022297824step_2( )..\install.php:13
```

I have the same problem,as the first commenter, but i don't know how to "close Notice message in your php ini file". What is that? Where can i find it? I use WAMP. Could it be a problem in a "real" server? (Not in localhost)

I can't go to the 3rd step because of the error. Help me please.

Comment: bad, dated tutorial, don't use it

Comment: Then please help me with some code. I really don't know how to do this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467892/how-to-create-install-php-including-steps-like-a-shopping-cart/22468320?noredirect=1#22468320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are suggesting to not display PHP notices, but I think it is bad advice because instead of fixing possible code problems that method just hides the message. Fixing the probem would be to initiate the variable:

`function step_2(){
    $pre_error = '';
    //...
}`

Answer (score 1):

Let me start off by saying turning off notices to hide your PHP errors is not very good practice at all!

Looking at the error, you cannot `echo` a non-existent variable. `$pre_error` is not defined in the case where things work correctly. You can declare this at the start of 'Step 2'.

```
function step_2(){
    $pre_error = '';
    if....
```

It would also be a good idea to update the conditionals in the if statements so that you check the array key exists before testing it's value.
E.g. `&& $_POST['pre_error'] != ''` should change to `&& (isset($_POST['pre_error']) && $_POST['pre_error'] != '')`

Answer (score 0):

Click on your WAMP icon in the taskbar > PHP > php.ini. This will bring you to the text file that sets up your basic PHP behaviors. You can customize those behaviors by following this reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Also, please don't make a PHP installation script. All sorts of security issues will rear their ugly head, especially if you're not using secure FTP over SSL.

Comment: I have to make a php installation script because my teacher told me. If i don't make an install.php, what is the best way to install my own little cms to anywhere?

Comment: @Dagon, you're right, it's never good to just shut off error reporting  and the reference does warn about this very explicitly. I just wanted to have darksoul pursue it on his own and know where his configurations files are.

Comment: @darksoul90, since something like 80% of coders are male, we have an 8 out of 10 chance of being right. And you know how coders like to be right... =P

Answer (score 0):

**To find your php.ini file:**

**Option 1:** Navigate to the corresponding folder on your computer and open the php.ini file with notepad. on mine it is specifically **C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin** (Your exact location and version of php may be slightly different.

**Option 2**
Click on the wamp icon in your system tray->PHP->php.ini

In notepad hit ctrl+f and search for `display_errors = On`. set this to `display_errors = Off`

Restart your wamp server and the notice should no longer be displayed

This is a very poor fix however as others have mentioned. I would also recommend you turn them back on when you are finished with that tutorials as displaying errors is invaluable when developing.